# Which book for Tensors and Differential Forms

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, differential-forms, tensors

Right now I'm looking for a basic to intermediate level book on tensors and differential forms as well as some light hodge theory. My attention has come between Renteln's "Manifolds, Tensors and Forms" and Tu and Bott's "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology". At the moment I'm going through Tu's Introduction to Manifolds to understand the basics of manifold theory but I find myself intrigued with aspects cohomology and hodge theory.

More importantly, is the quality of Renteln's book sufficient for understanding of differential forms and De Rham cohomology or would it be better to just to use some other texts on the same material?

Which one of the two would be best or would it be helpful to use Renteln's book as a supplement to understanding differential forms and the like.

Comment: IIRC, Renteln does a lot of this in the setting of vector spaces (which is applied later pointwise to tangent spaces of a manifold). Learning it first for vector spaces has the advantage of avoiding the manifold theory prerequisite.

Comment: There is no Hodge theory in Bott and Tu's book. But this book is always highly recommended.